# Difference between material and matter?

Tags: kant

Do you know what the difference is between material and matter?  Or does it mean the same thing in Kantian philosophy?

I'll give you an example:  "If a rational being can think of his maxims as practical universal laws, he can do so only by considering them as principles which contain the determining grounds of the will because of their form and not because of their matter."

(i get the form matter distinction in Hylomorphism/ even on Google when I searched Kant matter form distinction it says own form of Hylomorphism "is" and "ought" of object).

Here's where I have my question..does material mean the manifestation? or does it mean matter a/o form?  is matter a/o form the same as manifestation ?  what about precognition ?  Here is the quote:  "The material of a practical principle is the object of the will."

Comment: *material* adjective and *matter* noun ?

Comment: the material of the practical principle?

Answer (score 0):

Kant uses the word *matter* in his theoretical and practical philosophy either in the sense of *material* (as opposed to form - the original German is either *Materie* or *Stoff*) or in the sense of *what objects of the outer sense are made of* (in the *Metaphysical Foundations of Natural Science*), i.e. physical stuff.

The quotes you cite (from *Critique of Practical Reason*) use *material* and *matter* (in contrast with *form*) exchangeably. It's obvious from the context (one follows the other), but if you want further proof, there's the original German:

> **Lehrsatz III**
>
> Wenn ein vernünftiges Wesen sich seine Maximen als praktische allgemeine Gesetze denken soll, so kann es sich dieselbe nur als solche Principien denken, die nicht der **Materie**, sondern blos der Form nach den Bestimmungsgrund des Willens enthalten.
>
> **Die Materie eines praktischen Princips ist der Gegenstand des Willens.** [...]